# Can I apply for a Schengen visa from the French embassy if I don’t actually visit France?

Tags: visas, schengen

I have to travel to Germany soon and there are no dates available at the German consulate for a visa appointment for a month. I was thinking of getting a Schengen visa via the French embassy since that's the only one with dates available. I would be spending 12 or more days in Germany and a couple of days in Switzerland and Spain. Sadly, none of those embassys have dates either. 
Is that something I can do or would it land me in trouble?

Comment: You won't get in trouble, if you tell the truth, your application will just get rejected

Comment: JonathnReez my issue is the length of stay in the country which is your port if entry and which issues your visa. If i enter from France do I need to stay there for the maximum time? Will my longer stay in Germany be questioned?

Comment: @JonathanReez I don't think this is a duplicate. This question is, technically, answered by bullet-2, sub-bullet-3 of the fourth answer to the other question but that's rather hard to find. I don't think that's enough for closing as a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

According to schengen visa rules you can only apply through embassy/consulate which is your main destination.In your case your main destination is Germany and you can only apply from Germany.              Also Switzerland and Spain Will not accept your application because your are staying only 2 days there.                You can apply from France if you are spending more days in France. Or France is your first port of entry and you are spending equal number of days in each schengen country.   I can suggest you to split and show maximum number of days in France and Germany equally and apply from France. This is the only way France would accept your application

Comment: Thank you so much.  I am planning to spend an extra 5 days in Bordeaux, Cannes etc in France. That should make things smoother for me.

Comment: Welcome, to make look easier 5 nights in Germany,5 nights in France, and couple of nights in Spain and Switzerland